# Is it possible to include a File inside the Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file-io

Is there a way to include a File Content inside the Class ,not just *Text Files* but also *Binary Files* like a `Char Array` ,or `String` or whatever in Earth it could be ,so in **Constructor** my Class Should write That content into a **File** in a specified file .

This File can be an .exe , .pdf , .xls , .xml etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by include "a File Content inside the Class" but from what I'm guessing you mean (storing entire files inside a class?) you may want to look at Base64 encoding which is an encoding scheme that will let you convert any binary data into a ASCII string.

To store your binary data you can convert any `byte[]` into a Base64 encoded string using `Convert.ToBase64String` and store that in your class. To get it back use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get a `byte[]`.

Comment: Storing Entire File inside a class ,that exactly what i mean .

Comment: hi cbley that Worked like a Charm ,first i did FileStream stream = new FileStream("Date.exe", FileMode.Open); now i can Store a File as a String inside the class and write it wherever i want to .Best man .

Answer (score 1):

Like cbley, I'm not exactly sure what you mean either, but you could mean embedding a file in your assembly?

- Go into Visual Studio, click "add existing item" and choose your file.
- Change the Build Action on the file to "Embedded Resource"

When you run your application, you can extract the file binary to the file system like this.

```
//make sure MyNameSpace.MyFile.xls is the fully qualified name in your assembly to the file
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.Myfile.xls"))
{
   byte[] buf = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(buf, 0, stream.Length);
   File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\MyFile.xls", buf);
}
```

Comment: Not as resource because im going to export only a Class File ,not an DLL neither Executable .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `File.ReadAllBytes()` method.

Answer (score 0):

That would be possible, just store the file content as byte array. Write a converter which saves the bytes of a specified files into a text file in the format you need (so it represents an array). Then cut and paste this into your source code.